# add category with different attribute in spring boot

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have web site that every one can have advertisement .
All advertisements have category and admin can add category with different fields for example for selling house we have number of room but for car we have another option . I dont know what I should do for fields and how is sub category table.

```
 public class category{
private long id;
private String name;
@OneToMany
List<subcategory> sub;
}
```

How is sub category class with different fields for different category?

Comment: post code that you've tried?

Comment: Im not sure code help but i will add it

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Map rather than a subcategory object. This Map could contain the key and value of the fields on each case.

And remembeer to capitalize class names like java conventions says.

Comment: We have name ,  value and key from category .Correct?

Comment: You can have a Map using the category key as the key of map and category object as value of map